# How to Retrive Username from database unity then add Automatic login

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a login system and automatic login after login:

1. login from Google then retrieve username.
2. guest mode but retrieve the username from the firebase database.

I have 2 scenes on Unity scene no.1 is about login system and no.2 The game main menu. What I want from the scene no.1 is after they log in there will be username at the scene no.2. and if I exit the game then I open the app again will be automated login.

I have tried to retrieve but the username not changed,here the script.

SignManager.cs

```
public class SignManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public InputField nameText;
public static string playerName;
public static SignManager signManager;

User user = new User();

private void Awake()
{
    if (signManager != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        signManager = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}

public void onSubmit()
{
    playerName = nameText.text;
    posttodatabase();
}

public void posttodatabase()
{
    User user = new User();
    RestClient.Put("https://recruiter-wars.firebaseio.com/" + playerName + ".json", user);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Demo");
}
```

Retrieve.cs

```
User user = new User();

public Text namePlayer;
public static string playerName;

private void Start()
{
    RetrieveFromDatabase();
}

public void getUser()
{
    playerName = namePlayer.text;
}

public void RetrieveFromDatabase()
{
    RestClient.Get<User>("https://recruiter-wars.firebaseio.com/" + namePlayer + ".json").Then(ResponseHelper =>
    {
        user = ResponseHelper;
        getUser();
    });
}
```

[image: Login Menu at Scene 1]
[image: Input Username panel]
[image: Retrieve what on scene 1 to that panel]

im using RestClient for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally shouldn't do this. The path to your realtime database will be public knowledge to anyone who downloads your game. [Although you can use rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to secure it, typically you use the user id from Firebase Authentication is used to do so as it will be securely passed around with any database operation from the standard SDK.

With that said, I can tell you how I would accomplish what you want with the official Firebase SDK then give you hints that might help you with a third party rest-based client (I haven't used FirebaseREST myself).

For the [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup), I would use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) for this entire flow. I'm mostly following along with [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/google-signin).

Before you do anything, you will need to call `FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()`. I would use a continuation to ensure this succeeds. You only have to do it once per run of your game, but calling it multiple times won't hurt you more than the brief performance spikes it may cause:

```
async InitFirebase() {
    var result = await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
    if (result == DependencyStatus.Available) {
        // do Firebase stuff here
    }
}
```

Logging in is as simple as:

```
var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
var credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
var user = await auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
```

If you want the Firebase user in a new scene, or even a new launch of the game, you can call:

```
var user = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
```

If this is null you have to sign in again.

What's happening under the hood is that you pass user credentials in to the Firebase Authentication SDK. You can create or log in a user in your Firebase project there, and you get back a Firebase id token and a Firebase refresh token (you can get a little insight into this process [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions)).

The ID token is short lived (~1hr), but the refresh is valid until some event happens (ex: a user is deleted or disabled). You can choose to store this token in something like the Unity [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) (although you might want to be careful with it) and try to refresh the token the next time you launch the game. This will be way more secure than just reading a value from a database before authenticating a user.

If you want to persist the ID token between scenes, you can also try storing this in the PlayerPrefs. I would prefer a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) with a public property you can cache it in for the current run of your game, but that's up to your own preferences around persisting data between scenes (a MonoBehaviour singleton marked [DontDestoryOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) will work just as well for example).

I would recommend using the official [Unity Auth SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) if you can. This is one of the Firebase products that works on desktop and mobile.